# Auto expand the window by pressing a button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using “Microsoft Visual Studio 2010” and C# language. My user interface look like this(before user click the `Advance` button):
[image]

If user click `Advance` button, I want it to show the rest of the window as shown in the picture bellow:

[image]

Can you please tell me how can have all these information hidden till the user click the `Advance` button? How can I have a smaller window first, as shown in the first figure. And when the user press the `advance` button, it will expand and show the rest.
If you can show me with details, I would really appreciate it

Comment: `panel.Visible = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All WinForms controls, including the Form itself, have an `AutoSize` property. When set to `true`, it causes the control to automatically resize itself to fit its contents.

Therefore, you should place your "advanced" controls into a UserControl and add that UserControl to your form (or you can use a Panel if you're lazy). Then, when the "Advanced" button is clicked, toggle the visibility of your UserControl. The form should automatically adjust its size accordingly.

Alternatively, you could add [`SplitContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) to your form, which has the ability to collapse one of its two panels. The "Advanced" button would then toggle the state of the [`Panel2Collapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel2collapsed.aspx) property to expand/collapse the bottom panel.

Note: Grammatically, the caption of that button should be "Advanced", not "Advance". For an improved user experience, I recommend adding some kind of indicator that the button expands the available information on the window, rather than submitting it or opening a second window. Most "expander" buttons accomplish this using a downward-facing arrow, e.g.

[image]

You could use an image for this, or a Unicode glyph. For example, `▼`, the [black down-pointing triangle](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm). Change it to an upward-pointing triangle when the panel is expanded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, AutoSize property solved my problem. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: any one else reading this post: this.Size += new Size(100, 100); also worked. this.Size += new Size(width, height);

Comment: @Justin When manually adjusting the `Size` property, you shouldn't hardcode the sizes in pixels. Instead, you should query the actual size of the Panel to be hidden or shown. For example, `Form.Size += Panel.Size`. That way your code will work properly when DPI-based or other autoscaling is in effect.

Answer (score 2):

1.Add a panel to bottom of your form and add all the controls that you need to display in the advanced button click.

2.change the following properties of both the panel and your form,

```
   > AutoSize  >> true
   > AutoSizeMode  >> GrowAndShrink
```

3.then in form load event you can use like following

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

4. then in advanced button click event

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //panel1.Visible = true;
        string value1 = button1.Text;
        switch(value1)
        {
            case "Expand":
                panel1.Visible = true;
                break;
            case "Reduce":
                panel1.Visible = false;
                break;
        }
        button1.Text = "Reduce";
        if(panel1.Visible==true)
        {
            button1.Text = "Reduce";
        }
        else if(panel1.Visible==false)
        {
            button1.Text = "Expand";
        }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OnLoad event of your first form set every control or groupbox (whichever you are using) visibility as false.

And on advance buttonclick event make its visibility true.

Code as follows:

```
private void FirstForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  controlName.Visible=false;
}

 private void btnAdvance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     controlName.Visible=true;
 }
```

**MSDN For Visibility Property:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

At first set the following properties visible false
like all lebels and text boxs. then in the click event of the advanced button set all properties visible true.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It works well. but the screen size stays the same. can you please tell me, how can I have a smaller window first, as shown in the first figure. And when the user press the `advance` button, it will expand and show the rest

Comment: increase the windows height  when click event of advanced button will fire.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it like this,

1.Add a panel to bottom of your form and add all the controls that
    you need to display in the advanced button click.

2.change the following properties of both the panel and your form,

```
       > AutoSize  >> true
       > AutoSizeMode  >> GrowAndShrink
```

3.then in form load event you can use like following

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visible = false;
    }
```

4. then in advanced button click event

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visible = true;      
    }
```

Hope this will help you and any other need this in future...!